# I can not retrieve a list of objects from CosmosDb document

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I made a mistake with my SQL query with ComsosDb .NET SDK 3. I want to request a list of objects from a document.
This is my document as stored in CosmosDb (fid is partition key):

```
{
    "id": "1abc",
    "fid": "test",
    "docType": "Peeps",
    "People": [
        {
            "Name": "Bill",
            "Age": 99
        },
        {
            "Name": "Marion",
            "Age": 98
        },
        {
            "Name": "Seb",
            "Age": 97
        }
    ],
    "_rid": "mo53AJczKUuL9gMAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/mo53AA==/colls/mo53AJczKUs=/docs/mo53AJczKUuL9gMAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"9001cbc7-0000-1100-0000-60c9d58d0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1623840141
}
```

My results show an item count of 1 with properties set to default values - Name is null and Age is 0.
I was expecting a IEnumerable of 3 persons. Here is the code:

```
class MyPeople
{
   public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public async Task CosmosPeopleTest_ReturnsThreePeople()
{
   var config = GetConFig();
   var cosmosClientV2 = new CosmosClient(config["Cosmos:ConnectionString"]);
   var container = cosmosClientV2.GetContainer(config["Cosmos:DbName"], config["Cosmos:Collectionname"]);
   var sql = "SELECT c.People FROM c WHERE c.docType = 'Peeps'";
            QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sql);
   var results = new List<Person>();
   FeedIterator<Person> q = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Person>(queryDefinition, null, new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("test") });
   while (q.HasMoreResults)
   {
       var x = await q.ReadNextAsync();
       results.AddRange(x.ToList());
   }
   Assert.Equal(3, results.Count);
}
```

If I change the query to

```
 sql = "SELECT c.People FROM c JOIN d IN c.People";
```

I have three Person all with properties Name & Age which are defaults.

Comment: You are missing a root class.  The root object you are getting is not a person it is MyPeople.

Comment: I believe you have an issue with the types. `SELECT c.People` returns a list of `Person` and your code iterates `Person`s directly instead of "list of `Person`s". Since it using refactoring, it creates a `Person` object but can't fill its properties

Comment: I unfortunately can not get the code right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the types. `SELECT c.People` return an object in this form:

```
{
   People: [
      ...
   ]
}
```

When you iterate with this code

```
FeedIterator<Person> q = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Person>(queryDefinition, null, new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("test") });
```

The CosmosDB try to "convert" every result object (as above) to a `Person` class. But it using reflection for that. So it creates a `Person` object but doesn't find any fields to fill its properties - it will not fail, but create empty objects with all the properties initialized with default values.

So to solve it you need to use `MyPeople` instead of `Person`:

```
FeedIterator<MyPeople> q = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyPeople>(queryDefinition, null, new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("test") });
```

Since `MyPeople` is the right form of the returned object, it will be able to read the objects that the CosmosDB returns and use them.

The full working code:

```
var config = GetConFig();
var cosmosClientV2 = new CosmosClient(config["Cosmos:ConnectionString"]);
var container = cosmosClientV2.GetContainer(config["Cosmos:DbName"], config["Cosmos:Collectionname"]);
var sql = "SELECT c.People FROM c WHERE c.docType = 'Peeps'";
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sql);
var results = new List<Person>();
FeedIterator<MyPeople> q = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyPeople>(queryDefinition, null, new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("test") });
while (q.HasMoreResults)
{
   var x = await q.ReadNextAsync();
   var myPeopleRes = x.Resource;

   foreach (var people in myPeopleRes)
   {
       results.AddRange(people.People);
   }
}
Assert.Equal(3, results.Count);
```

Comment: So you have to return the whole document and then extract the List<T> ? Is there no way to just return the List<T> ?

Comment: It is not returning the whole document, but an object with just `People` field and nothing else, exactly like `MyPeople`. You won't be able to read other fields like `docType` for example